# Access values from cookies using sencha extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, cookies

I am pretty new to [sencha](/questions/tagged/sencha) as well as JavaScript. So can you please help me with how to use Sencha ExtJS and extract information from cookies. I have set the state of a gridpanel in cookies and now I want to extract the value of columnOrder and other information from cookies.

Any code or reference will be really appreciated.

Comment: But you'll immediately get into licensing problems with this approach: sencha could be used free of license fees, but if you use ExtJS (as it was proposed you) you'll have to pay. So, it's easier to write your proper class (or use any opensource one available on WEB).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

First thing - if you haven't found these already, here is a link to the **Ext docs**:

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs

Second - here is a link to *Ext.util.Cookies*:

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.util.Cookies

Example of use:

```
// write cookie
var myCookie = Ext.util.Cookies.set('YourCookieName', 'YourValue');

// read cookie
Ext.util.Cookies.get('YourCookieName');
```

Answer (score 0):

**Write cookie**

```
var myCookie = Ext.util.Cookies.set('YourCookieName', 'YourValue');
```

**Read cookie**

```
Ext.util.Cookies.get('YourCookieName');
```